# Deny direct access to a directory that have a redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following situation:

My server have a `output` directory, that should never be accessed directly, instead, the root url should be redirected to it:

- Accessing `mydomain.com/test.html` will internally show the content of `output/test.html`.
- Acessing `mydomain.com/output/test.html` should return an 404

The first point is easily archived by using this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!output/)(.*)$ output/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that if I try to direct access `mydomain.com/output/test.html` it also allows.

I've tried to add this second rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^output/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^output - [F]
```

But it apparently affects the first one, so anything gets accessible on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition pattern is wrong. You need to match against the full `THE_REQUEST` string.

Change your RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^output/ [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /output/ [NC]
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't noticed that THE_REQUEST includes the slash. Actually it includes the entire URL instead of the URI like the RewriteRule do.